# Getting Error While Send Mail from website and sent messages are in spam(with warning alert)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting Below warning message after send a mail from website... 
and mails are received with warning message (potentially unsafe)...

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: **mail(/var/log/php-mail.log) [function.mail]: failed to open stream: Permission denied**
>
> Filename: **libraries/Email.php**
>
> Line Number: **1554**

Comment: The user that PHP is running as, cannot access that file. You need to check your permissions for that location.

Comment: shall i know which file? and where it is?

Comment: The file is listed in the error `/var/log/php-mail.log`

Comment: A possible reason you're seeing the error in emails sent when from localhost and not live is because your local configuration will show warnings while your live configuration will probably be set not to show any errors. This is pretty standard. Still, on your localhost, the problem is that PHP is unable to access the file shown in the error message.

Comment: shall i know the proper way of mail implementation from start to end... any reference ? @Relequestual

Comment: @Relequestual i am sending mail from live only, not from localhost

Comment: What do you not understand about the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry about i answer this question , i must add comment but i can't ;)
two important thing about sending mail: 1-permission's.
2- mail only work on live server not localhost.

then you can add code like :

```
$name = $this -> input -> post("name");
            $email = $this -> input -> post("email");
            $comment = $this -> input -> post("comment");
            $config = Array('protocol' => 'smtp', 'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com', 'smtp_port' => 465, 'mailtype' => 'html', 'charset' => 'utf-8', 'wordwrap' => TRUE);
            $this -> load -> library('email', $config);
            $this -> email -> set_newline("\r\n");
            $email_setting = array('mailtype' => 'html');
            $this -> email -> initialize($email_setting);
            $this -> email -> from("'" . $email . "'", "'" . $name . "'");

            $this -> email -> to('something@somthing.com');
            $this -> email -> subject("'" . $name . "'");
            $this -> email -> message($comment);

            $this -> email -> send();
```

wish it is useful.. :)

Comment: You should be able to edit your question, which is preferable to adding an answer or making a comment, when you have new information.

Comment: @Mohseb mail not received and no error, i sent mail from live not localhost